# Javascript executed on console executes, but how to execute a javascript to a page placed on iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I need to screenshot a youtube video. But the biggest difficulty is cross orgin security issue. Javascript code of htmltocanvas executes successfully and generate a base64 image when it is executed in console on youtube site, but not in an embed iframe.

Is there any backend processing to get screenshot? Or can this be solved using javascript itself?

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/ReeganExE/youtube-screenshot) helps

Comment: No @TusharWalzade.. this works by executing the javascript on the browser url itself. But i want to know how to do that using iframe embed.

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/Wvaca/)

Comment: This doesnt work for youtube